# How to get high-resolution plots in a Jupyter notebook using the R kernel?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

Using SVG in a Jupyter notebook with R kernel mangles the text.  See [here](http://compbio.ucsd.edu/outputting-beautiful-jupyter-notebooks-r-kernel-edition/#html-output-mangled-graphics-text) and [here](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/129).  The workaround is to use PNG.  It's a bit blurry. In Python, you can ask the PNG renderer to use more dots per inch with

```
 InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'
```

See for example [trick 15 here](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/jupyter-notebook-tips-tricks-shortcuts/).

How can I get higher resolution plots using the R kernel? SVG workaround? PNG renderer settings?

*Edit*: I'm using ggplot in R.

*Edit 2*: I found `repr.plot` defaults [here](https://github.com/IRkernel/repr/blob/master/R/options.r#L51-L61), including res, which looks to be dots per inch (dpi).  However, when I raise the `res` from 120 to 300, the plot gets bigger, despite me setting height and width.

*Edit 3*: I filed [this issue](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/458).  There are suggestions for how to fix it in the code, but no workarounds.

Comment: I havent tried this myself, but try using options, like proposed here, maybe there's a setting for the default dpi: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61556331/how-to-set-default-image-plot-size-in-r-on-jupyter-notebook 

Also, maybe you can set other defaults for the svg function, refer to the help of the svg function in the grDevices package.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently discover that packages : plotly can work well on creating ggplot images

try the **plot_ly()** function to save png pics

[here is a demo using plot_ly](https://github.com/GMfatcat/plotly_demo)

hope this can help!