# How to set default image/plot size in R on jupyter notebook?

Tags: css, r, plot, jupyter-notebook

I used to have my plots printed on the screen as 840 x 840 images using Jupyter notebook (R kernel).
However, for some reason, Jupyter started to print them as 420 x 420. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llW43.png) is an example. When I right-click the image and "inspect" it, I see the following:

```
<img src="data: (...suppressed...)" height="420" width="420">
```

I can change both height and width manually after the plot is on the screen (by editing the numbers above), but every time I run the cell again I go back to the 420 x 420 format. Ideally, I wanted a way to set image/plot height and width parameters for all cells at once. I've tried to add a custom.css file to my .jupyter folder, but could not figure out how to set image sizes.

Just to make it clear, my problem is not with R (plotting specs), but with how Jupyter generates the Html file that shows the plot on my screen.

In addition, solutions like

```
options(repr.plot.width = X, repr.plot.height = Y)
```

do not help as the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7TeC.png) illustrates (axis labels and legends do not adjust proportionally to the selected plot size). It is different from the 840 x 840 image I used to get before ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LLPZ.png)).

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I met this problem several days ago and saw your question. After checking many configurations, I find a solution to it.

In jupyter R notebook, run `options()`

You can find this in the output

```
$jupyter.plot_scale
$[1] 2
```

This means that the plot size is halfed.
Therefore running `options(jupyter.plot_scale=1)` will set the plot size to its full size.

I have no idea why and how this default value is changed, but this solution works for me.

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't affect the size of my plot at all. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this:

```
library("repr")
options(repr.plot.width=12.7, repr.plot.height=8.5)
```

and it definitely works in JupyterHub Version 2.3.1. For reference here is the output of `jupyter --version`:

```
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.4.0
ipykernel        : 6.13.1
ipywidgets       : 7.7.0
jupyter_client   : 7.3.4
jupyter_core     : 4.10.0
jupyter_server   : 1.18.1
jupyterlab       : 3.4.4
nbclient         : 0.6.4
nbconvert        : 6.5.0
nbformat         : 5.4.0
notebook         : 6.4.12
qtconsole        : not installed
traitlets        : 5.2.2
```